# How many bytes would a string occupy, initialized for less letters

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization

I need to know how many Bytes would this array occupy:

```
char s[10] = "test";
```

Will it be 10 Bytes or 5 Bytes because of `"test" + "\0"` ?

Comment: Allocated memory is 10 bytes anyway, independently on how is initialized, defult initialized, etc. The first 5 bytes are meaning (test+\0), the remaining meaningless (`'\0'` or whatever).

Comment: Why does one worry about 5 bytes?

Answer (score 2):

Just to clear things out a bit

```
 char s[10] = "test";
```

here `s` will occupy 10 bytes, as you have explicitly supplied the size.

OTOH, a definition like

```
 char s[ ] = "test";
```

`s` will occupy 5 bytes, as the size of the array will be determined based on the supplied initializer (4 elements plus one null-terminator.)

In case of a `char` array, the second one is considered a better approach, as at times, it may save you from the trouble by forgetting to count the space for null-terminator while defining the size.

Consider the scenario,

```
 char arr[5] = "Hello";
```

here, `arr` will be of size 5 and is **not** null terminated. But if you use

```
 char arr[ ] = "Hello";
```

compiler will automatically determine the size including the null terminator. So, `arr` will be of size 6 and include the null-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

In your question there are in fact two separate questions. The first one  corresponds to the title of the original question

> How many bytes would a string occupy, initialized for less letters

and the second one is in the body of the original question

> how many Bytes would this array occupy:

```
char s[10] = "test";
```

The answer to the first question sounds like the string occupies exactly 5 elements of the array. That is the string occupies the following elements of the array

```
s[0] = 't', s[1] = 'e', s[2] = 's', s[3] = 't', s[4] = '\0'
```

all other characters of the array in the range `[5, 9]` will be initialized by zero `'\0'`

And the answer to the second your question sounds like the array occupies exactly the size that equal to `10 * sizeof( char )` that is exactly `10 bytes` because `sizeof( char )` is always equal to `1`.

If you would write instead

```
char s[] = "test";
      ^^
```

then the size of the array would be equal to the size of the string literal (including the terminating zero) that is to 5 characters.